# Multiplying pandas DataFrames of different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have 2 pandas DataFrames.

The first one contains data on firm's annual reports for public companies in the US. In other words, every observation (row) contains data on one single firm in one single year.

The second DataFrame has data on average annual inflation levels.

I have to multiply the all values from the first df with the inflation level for the appropriate year in the second df. How can I go about it?

```
Example DataFrames

df1:

index    year    firm    assets    ppe    other_variable
  0      2000     1        50       2           5
  1      2001     1        60       3           5
  2      2000     2        30       5          10
  3      2001     2        45       5           8
  4      2002     2        50      10           8
...

df2:

year    cpi
2000    1.000
2001    1.010
2002    1.022
...
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the dataframes?

Comment: Do a join between the two dataframes

Comment: @SreeramTP added an example. As you can see, in df1 the same year can appear more than once whereas in df2 each year only appears once.

Comment: Try ```df1.join(df2.set_index('year'), on='year', how='left')```.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiple all columns without first selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by mapped values by `year`, if no match are created missing values so replaced by `1` in `fillna` if necessary and multiple by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
y = df1['year'].map(df2.set_index('year')['cpi']).fillna(1)
df1.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.iloc[:, 1:].mul(y, axis=0)
print (df1)
   year   firm  assets    ppe  other_variable
0  2000  1.000   50.00   2.00           5.000
1  2001  1.010   60.60   3.03           5.050
2  2000  2.000   30.00   5.00          10.000
3  2001  2.020   45.45   5.05           8.080
4  2002  2.044   51.10  10.22           8.176
```

Another idea is add column `cpi` to first `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and then mupliple with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
df = df1.set_index('year').join(df2.set_index('year'))
df = df.mul(df.pop('cpi'), axis=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   year   firm  assets    ppe  other_variable
0  2000  1.000   50.00   2.00           5.000
1  2000  2.000   30.00   5.00          10.000
2  2001  1.010   60.60   3.03           5.050
3  2001  2.020   45.45   5.05           8.080
4  2002  2.044   51.10  10.22           8.176
```